# Sitecore 9.1.0 Deployment to Azure, MSbuild issues

Tags: azure-devops

For my deployment, I'm using the Hosted Agent VS2017 (the only one with .NET 4.7.2). There seem to be a problem in this one, as mentionned in the following github feed : https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901.

The `agent` uses `MSBUILD` 15.0 and not 15.2 which fixes the bug of Publish files. Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem ? (I cannot directly update the hosted agent so I'm stuck here)

How did you proceed to build your Sitecore solutuon on `Azure DevOps` ?

Did you use this hosted agent or not ?

Comment: You should not be targeting .NET 4.7.2 on Sitecore 9.1.0. Target .NET 4.7.1.

Comment: Please update your question with your publish profile and parameters. I am not having any issues publishing WDPs on Azure Devops.